# electron-forge: how to specify hooks?

Tags: javascript, electron, packaging, electron-forge

### Goal

I want to get rid of some folders before the electron-forge's packaging step, because the option `ignore.roge.config` in `package.json` does not get rid of all the intermediate folders that I specify to ignore for some packages. Those intermediate folders are usually generated during a native build process during packaging.

### Problem

But adding `hooks` field [with the documented events](https://www.electronforge.io/configuration#hooks) don't seem to work, e.g.,

having a `package.json` field like this seems to add nothing to the equation, i.e., I don't see the expected console log.

```js
  "config": {
    "forge": {
      "packagerConfig": {
        "icon": "src/images/myapp",
        "ignore": [
          "/.gitignore",
          "/.vscode",
          "/yarn.lock",
          "/node_modules/mydep/build/",
          "/node_modules/mydep/prebuilds/linux*"
        ]
      },
      "hooks": {
          "prePackage": "async () => {\"console.log("this is prepackage step.");\"} "
      },
      "makers": [
        {
          "name": "@electron-forge/maker-zip",
          "platforms": [
            "darwin",
            "win32"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  },
```

Referring to [a related elctron-forge github issue](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-forge/issues/197), I've also tried to feed a JS source file to hooks

```js
"hooks": "require:./hooks.js",
```

where the hooks script looks like

```js
{
    prePackage: async () => {
        console.log('this is prepackage step.');
    }
}
```

This didn't work either.

Worse, I can't even specify multiple hooks this way:

```js
{
    generateAssets: async () => {
        console.log('We should generate some assets here');
    },
    prePackage: async (forgeConfig, options) => {
        console.error('lbn: prePackage');
    }
}
```

The above code gives me the following error when running `yarn make`:

```
An unhandled error has occurred inside Forge:
Unexpected token ':'
/path/to/myapp/hooks.js:5
    prePackage: async (forgeConfig, options) => {
              ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1116:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1164:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1220:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1049:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:937:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1089:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:73:18)
    at renderConfigTemplate (/path/to/myapp/node_modules/@electron-forge/core/src/util/forge-config.ts:100:20)
    at _default (/path/to/myapp/node_modules/@electron-forge/core/src/util/forge-config.ts:145:3)
    at /path/to/myapp/node_modules/@electron-forge/core/src/api/make.ts:96:19
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

### Question

What is the right way to specify hooks?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solved it myself.

We should place the hooks as a normal global module

```js
// ./hooks.js

const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {

postPackage: async (forgeConfig, options) => {
    console.warn('\n\npostPackage: exclude files ...\n\n');
}

}; // module.exports = {
```

Then refer to it in `package.json`

```json
"hooks": "require:./hooks.js",
```

Comment: Source? I'm pretty new to electron-forge but I'm not seeing this approach (of using `require` in `hooks` in the `package.json`) on any of their docs

Comment: @1owk3y well, I use it in my production code so I guess that's at least some proof...